# JFormattedTextField not update text after setText() in a event

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

Why after this event perfomed  the `JFormattedTextField` object not update text??

why after `setText("")` called the text is clear but after `jComboBox1ItemStateChanged` again with another state the last text is back

```
       public class AddItem extends JDialog {
        public ArrayList< JFormattedTextField> jtxts = new ArrayList<>();

           public AddItem(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
              super(parent, modal);
              initComponents();
              for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                 jtxts.add(new JFormattedTextField());
                 jtxts.get(i).setVisible(false);
                 jtxts.get(i).setBounds(450, 80 + i * 40, 100, 20);
                 add(jtxts.get(i));

                 jlabels.add(new JLabel());
                 jlabels.get(i).setBounds(560, 80 + i * 40, 100, 20);
                 jlabels.get(i).setVisible(false);
                 jlabels.get(i).setLabelFor(jtxts.get(i));
                 add(jlabels.get(i));

              }

           }

      private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                    
           switch (jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex()) {

              case 0:
                 hideJtxtAndJlabels();
                 showJtxtAndJlabels(3);
                 break;
              case 1:
                 hideJtxtAndJlabels();                 
                 showJtxtAndJlabels(2);        
                 break;                        
          }
        }
    public void showJtxtAndJlabels(int size) {
          for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

             jtxts.get(i).setVisible(true);
             jlabels.get(i).setVisible(true);
          }
       }
private void hideJtxtAndJlabels() {
      for (int i = 0; i < jlabels.size(); i++) {
         System.out.println(jtxts.get(i).getText()); //print the last text
         jtxts.get(i).setText("");
         System.out.println(jtxts.get(i).getText()); //print "" but after change state jcombobox1 the last text is back
         jlabels.get(i).setVisible(false);
         jtxts.get(i).setVisible(false);

      }
   }


    }
```

Comment: `""` is likely not a valid value for the `JFormattedTextField` and it's resorting to the last known "good" value the field has within it's model.  You should be using `set/getValue` instead